# How to test a void method returns if condition satisfied

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

How to test this?

```cs
public void TestMethod()
{
   if(aDenpendency.someMethod()) return;

   // Followed by other logic....
}
```

I don't have another dependency in the following logic, so I couldn't use AssertWasNotCalled.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should test logic/behaviour, and from your code example is not clear what are you going to test, please show a full method and give more details

Comment: @sll I think he is asking how he can assert that `return` has been called at a certain point in the void method rather than the method just returning when it ends.

Comment: Thanks Robbie, it was my intention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a mistake to test as you are describing. And denotes poor code structure and is a definate **code smell**, you should refactor and unit test that code, Given that you aim to test it has not been called it follows you also want a test when it has been called.

You need to have a method have a single responsibility,therefore for more sensible unit testing you can take out the logic after the return encase it in a method and unit test the output of that method.

A unit test is not there to test what was not called it is there to either test an expectation setup by a mock/fake or you should test the result of the operation.

You could write a test that tests the state of the object once the method has been called but this is really an integration test rather than a unit test. That means you can test the state that is as should be after the return statement has executed the other code will not have executed so whatever that modifies or processes will not have been modified.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with testing that e.g. a sort routine calls the comparison function the correct number of times, if that is part of the specification.  Or how else would you recommend detecting `O(N^3)` behavior?

Comment: Ben I am saying that you shouldn't test for what hasn't been called. Plus testing anything that is state outside of the method is outside of A.A.A unit test style (Arrange Act Assert) that is more of a integration test as you are no longer testing the unit of code more the results. That is if i understand your point correctly.

Comment: And I'm saying I see nothing wrong with testing that something hasn't been called.  I can't immediately think of an example for C#, but in C++ you might want to verify that a particular function doesn't make a copy of its argument, if it is a large data structure (copy in C++ tends to be an expensive deep copy).  Oh, here's one:  In C# you might want to test that a particular method runs based on cached results, and doesn't cause a new database query.

Comment: Sorry Ben I disagree but thats ok :) You could solve this in integration rather than unit tests as described. But I accept this is my opinion and that others (in this case yourself) may disagree

Comment: Thanks Krystan, I agree. This kind of code are everywhere in our solution and I don't believe it's unit testable. But if in the following logic there is another dependency not wrapped with condition, we are able to use assertwasnotcalled to work around.

Comment: Yup and upon reflection I think this is what Ben was getting at. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

What about having the method you are testing set a 'Status' property eg something like Running\Processing\Aborted etc?

So you would call your void method under whatever test situation you are setting up and then check the property afterwards. The return; and Status properties setting would be together in the code

```
if(condition){
    _status = 1; //Or use an enumeration would be better
    return;
}
```

Your test would then test the status via public Accessor.

This may not be appropriate in all cases but I am looking at doing something like this where my class has a void method Process(). It will probably make your test simpler, with you not needing a mock (but may need stubs still) and will mean you can postively test if something DID happen as opposed to something that DIDN'T happen (I agree with previous poster that this is a better approach where possible)

I realised this might smell of writing code just to allow testing but in my particular case I am going to use the public property for checking the state of the class during actual running of code so this whole approach is consistent with the overall design.